# python how to parse tags in specified div tag

Tags: python, regex

i already tried the other solutions on this site but still couldn't solve the problem and here my problem is:

```
<div class="ds"><div title="Today" class="dh">...<div title="Pazartesi" class="dh">26 Agu Pzt
```

I want to parse all the div titles in this "ds" class, thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4954037 tldr: it might be better to use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (instead of regex) to parse html.

Comment: Plese add expected output as well.

Comment: What have you tried already? We cannot help you if you don't show the code and the error messages you get.

Comment: use `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` or similar module instead of `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` or similar module instead of `regex`.

---

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '<div class="ds"><div title="Today" class="dh">...<div title="Pazartesi" class="dh">26 Agu Pzt'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.ds div[title]'):
    print(item['title'])

# or as list comprehensions    

titles = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('.ds div[title]')]
print(titles)
```

---

[lxml](https://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.html

text = '<div class="ds"><div title="Today" class="dh">...<div title="Pazartesi" class="dh">26 Agu Pzt'

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

for item in soup.cssselect('.ds div[title]'):
    print(item.attrib['title'])

# or as list comprehensions    

titles = [item.attrib['title'] for item in soup.cssselect('.ds div[title]')]
print(titles)
```

---

[PyQuery](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html):

```
import pyquery

text = '<div class="ds"><div title="Today" class="dh">...<div title="Pazartesi" class="dh">26 Agu Pzt'

soup = pyquery.PyQuery(text)

for item in soup('.ds div[title]'):
    print(item.attrib['title'])

# or as list comprehensions    

titles = [item.attrib['title'] for item in soup('.ds div[title]')]
print(titles)
```

---

[parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): (used by [Scrapy's Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html))

```
import parsel

sel = parsel.Selector(text)

for item in sel.css('.ds div[title]'):
    print(item.attrib['title'])

titles = [item.attrib['title'] for item in sel.css('.ds div[title]')]
print(titles)
```